# Extreme point is optimal for LP on unbounded set?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider an LP with an unbounded feasible region, but whose objective is bounded. Maybe something like

$$\max x_1-x_2$$
$$\text{s.t. }x_1\le 1$$
$$x_1,x_2\ge 0$$

The proofs I've seen that at least one extreme point is optimal all assume that the feasible region is bounded, so that any point in the feasible region is a convex combination of extreme points. This isn't true here, though - is there an alternative way to prove this?

Comment: The feasible region might have no extreme points. Trivially, $\min \{ 0 | x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: Yes, it has no extreme points iff it contains a line. But in the case that the set does have an extreme point and is still unbounded, how do I show that at least one of the extreme points is optimal?

Comment: Simple: put additional bounds on the region. Take your example. Sure your example has an unbounded region, but obviously since $x_2= 1$ is in the region, there is no reason to allow to look for $x_2 > 1$ since any such points will be lower than for the same $x_1$ and $x_2 = 1$.  If no such additional bounds are possible, then the LP has no extremum.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I had thought about that, though I wasn't sure if I would be able to add additional bounds without messing with the optimality of the LP. I think I should be able to work it out though.